# How to grep the word between two symbols in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I need to grep the word between the symbols as shown below in an array.

```
my $string = "?hi how r u?what is your name?what is your age?";
```

It's to be converted to array where array should be like:

```
my $array[0]="hi how r u";
my $array[1]="what is your name";
my $array[2]="what is your age";
```

Comment: [`perldoc split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)

Comment: `my @array = grep /\S/, split /\?/, $string`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) function, however you have to escape the `?` character, so that it won't get special treatment as part of a regular expression control character.

```
 my @array = split '\\?', $string;
```

Comment: Note also that there will be empty elements in the resulting array where `?` is adjacent to nothing, or if you have two next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

To ignore empty results you can match the input with regex and store matched results in an array:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "?hi how r u?what is your name?what is your age?";
my @matches = ( $string =~ /(?<=\?)[^?]+/g );

foreach my $i (@matches) {
   print $i . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
hi how r u
what is your name
what is your age
```